# Repulsorlift generators on Star Wars capital ships

Tags: star-wars, technology

We know that the *Acclamator* and *Venator* classes, along with *Lucrehulk* core ships, can land on planets, but none of these ships can do so without repulsorlift generators. On the other hand, ISDs and larger ships are devoid of such items or have reduced capacity to use them but that's partially due to their inability to operate closer to planetary surfaces than high atmosphere.

How big are the repulsorlift generators onboard these ships?

Comment: hmmmmmm  wasnt a star destroyer in the rebels pilot in low atmosphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the evidence of the [Star Wars: Incredible Cross Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) and [Star Wars: Force Awakens - Incredible Cross Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections), Imperial Star Destroyers and their successor craft don't have any obvious repulsorlift components, nor do they appear to possess the ability to make planetary landings.

Assuming the repulsorlift components on a Venator craft are of a comparable size to those on an Acclamator-class Republic Assault ship then you would expect them to comprise around 5 percent of the total size of the vessel and no more than a few tens of metres in length.

[image]

Note that the repulsorlift panels seen in an X-Wing take up roughly the same amount of space.

[image]

Comment: Scaling items up or down can be a little tricky. You would assume that the volume of a repulsorlift generator would be proportional to the mass of the vehicle it is installed on. The generator may take up a square with side about 5% of the largest dimension of an X-Wing (and with most SW ships the largest dimension is going to be length) and 10-15cm high, but the main constraint on a SW landing gear is its load-bearing surface. So I would think the volume taken up by repulsorlifts on a ship grows faster than linear as a relationship to the mass of said ship.

Comment: @NSERCProtester - The fact that they're utterly absent from the cross-section of a Venator-Class Star Destroyer leads me to the impression that they're really quite small. Sufficiently small as to not merit a single mention. It's guesswork though.

Comment: On the Acclamator, it is in the tail fin; if I had to guess it would be about 20-25m in diameter for about 30-40m in length.

For the Venator, it may well be hidden either between ion drives and the main reactor or underneath the main reactor... cross-sections can't show everything

Comment: @NSERCProtester - Good point and worthy of an edit.